# Python v3.3.5 maths questions program

Tags: python-3.x

Does anybody know why the score counter isn't working in this program? The program is designed to run 10 random maths questions and then display the score. However although it asks the questions, it will always display the score as being '0'

```
name = input('Type in your name')
questioncount = 0
score = 0

import random
for questioncount in range(0,10):
    number1 = random.randrange(1,13)
    number2 = random.randrange(1,13)
    sign = random.randrange(1,4)

    if (sign) == 1 :
        print('{}x{}'.format(number1, number2))
    elif (sign) == 2 :
        print ('{}+{}'.format(number1, number2))
    elif (sign) == 3 :
        print ('{}-{}'.format(number1, number2))

    answer = input('What is the answer?')

    if (sign) == 1:
        if (answer) == number1*number2:
            score == score+1
        else:
            pass

    if (sign) == 1:
        if (answer) == number1+number2:
            score == score+1
        else:
            pass

    if (sign) == 1:
        if (answer) == number1-number2:
            score == score+1
        else:
            pass

pass
print('you got {} answers right!'.format(score))
```

Comment: Does the program enter the `if`s that increment the score?

Comment: "score == score+1" should be "score = score + 1" ??

Comment: Testing `if (sign) == 1:` three times in a row is _very_ suspicious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some problems:

- You forgot to change the numbers in the if statements.
- You have to parse the input of the answer into int because input returns a string.
- `score == score+1` is a comparison and it always returns false. It should be "=". `score = score + 1` or in a shorter way `score += 1` is exactly the same
- 2 ifs nested for just one thing could be written in the same if statement.

You wrote this:

```
if (sign) == 2:
    if (answer) == number1+number2:
        score += 1
    else:
        pass
```

It could be:

```
if (sign) == 2 and (answer) == number1+number2:
    score += 1
```

- You should use `if/elif` statements instead of `else:pass`

This way

```
if (sign) == 1 and (answer) == number1*number2:
        score += 1
elif (sign) == 2 and (answer) == number1+number2:
    score += 1
elif (sign) == 3 and (answer) == number1-number2:
    score += 1
```

and even better

```
if (sign == 1 and answer == number1 * number2) or (sign == 2 and answer == number1 + number2) or (sign == 3 and answer == number1 - number2) :
    score += 1
```

That said, I would write this program like this:

```
import random
name = input('Type in your name\n')
score = 0

for _ in range(10):
    number1 = random.randrange(1,13)
    number2 = random.randrange(1,13)
    sign = random.choice(["*", "+", "-"])
    expression = "{0} {1} {2}".format(number1,sign,number2)
    print(expression)
    answer = int(input('What is the answer?\n'))
    print("-------------")
    if answer == eval(expression):
        score += 1

print('{}, you got {} right answers!'.format(name, score))
```

**Notes:**

The use of `_` it's because it is not important. You can call it whatever you want and you don't even have to declare it before.

The `\n` means carriage return.

You should do some more changes to prevent user from writting others characters in the answer, but I think you have work enough to do with this.